# What is the best way to sync CRM and POS with WooCommerce?

Tags: woocommerce, crm

Our client is a UK based shop, has two physical shops and one online e-commerce store running WooCommerce. The client needs to sync his stock and POS with WooCommerce. What do you recommend?
He is willing to change his current CRM that does not have integration with Woo (Microsoft Dynamics) but I do not know what to recommend him.

Comment: Will this workout for you https://wordpress.org/plugins/product-import-export-for-woo ?

Comment: For CRM , please checkout this https://wordpress.org/plugins/wsdesk/

Answer (score 0):

ViceSoft made a plugin to integrate Microsoft Dynamics CRM with WooCommerce. You can have a look at it [here](http://www.vicesoft.com/dynamics-crm-woocommerce-integration-orders-invoices/).